# How to add a new foreign key field in model django without migration error?

Tags: python, django, database, migration

I have two models A, B, they contain a lot of data(int database). Suddenly I decided to add a foreign key in model B to A. But Django can't migrate it because existing rows in table B haven't value for this FK. What should I do in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

in foreignkey attribute add **default=None**

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
class ModelB(models.Model):
column_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None)
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation.